# How to get the detail from the table 'ALL_Lists" in ALM using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, alm

I am working on the REST API and encounter a problem awaiting for the help from the forum.

My request is to collect the information from 'ALL_Lists' so that I can setup the treeview to display the test folder structure in the Test Plan, I know how to achieve it using OTA, however don't have any idea what URL it should be using REST API, please help.

Answer (score 0):

HP ALM help file has all the information you need to get started.

Afte you login to HP ALM (Thin Client), GoTO HELP -> API Reference -> RESTFUl API.

This would help someone who is new to HP REST API.

To find available HP API end-points,
GET /qcbin/rest/resouce-list

Comment: Barney, I also want to ask, if I have known the subject folder name which i need to query is "Subject\Test Case 1", which API request I can send to get the detail information under this folder? such as child folder name, test case under each folder? appreciate in advance if you can give me more instructions